# Using window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight makes scrollbars appear

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, viewport

I'm trying to make a simple canvas that stretches itself to fully fill the viewport, but I don't want scrollbars to appear, a thing that happens if I try to resize the canvas in JS using `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`.

Note: I don't want to resize the canvas in CSS because the elements inside get all stretched out since from what I've understood the CSS treats the canvas as an img, and doesn't actually stretch the resolution of the canvas.

This is what happens: 
[image]
This is the code:
css:

```
    html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

/*canvas*/
#bg {
    background: #171629;
}
```

js:

```
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.canvas.width  =  window.innerWidth
ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight


ctx.rect(20, 40, 50, 50)
ctx.fillStyle = "#e5e5e5"
ctx.fill()
ctx.closePath()
```

Comment: `ctx.canvas.height = window.innerWidth` - well, you meant innerHeight, right?

Comment: You forgot to set `padding: 0` to `html, body {`

Comment: I agree with @Oen44: it must be `ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight` . If so you may want to use `body{width:100vw; height:100vh;overflow:hidden;}`

Comment: Yeah I meant innerHeight, still that wasn't the problem

Comment: Can you provide an example we can play with? your problem probably is that it's just a bit bigger than 100% so it shows the scrollbar.
You can try add overflow:none to the css but it's not really fixing the problem rather than just sweeping it under the carpet

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but still doesn't have any correct answer, so I will post my answer here for anyone looking for a solution.

If you want to get rid of the scrollbars when setting canvas width/height to the window's width/height just display canvas as block:

```
  * { 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
  }
  canvas {  
    display: block;  /* <---- As simple as that */
  }
```

You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

After a bunch of trying I found this as a solution:

css:

```
html,
body {
  display:flex;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

js:

```
canvasElement.height = window.innerHeight;
canvasElement.width = document.body.clientWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

css:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, My problem was when I typed

```
<style type="text/csss">
  body{
      margin:0;
      overflow:hidden;
  }
  canvas{
      background-color:lightblue;
  }</style>
```

instead of:

```
<style type="text/css">
  body{
      margin:0;
      overflow:hidden;
  }
  canvas{
      background-color:lightblue;
  } </style>
```

a tiny grammatical mistake can make you suffer a lot